# How to add a color gradient to a radar plot based on different absolute values at the center

Tags: r, radar-chart, spider-chart

I'm using fmsb package for radarplots on r to show the mean differences in grades in subjects V1-V9 compared to an arbitrary  value (center of the radar plot). I would like the plot to convey this arbitrary value somehow and a color gradient would be a reasonable way to do it (almost like a heatmap). This would help compare two radar plots to one another when the arbitrary value is different

I'm using fmsb package for radarplots on r to show the mean differences in grades in subjects V1-V9 compared to an arbitrary  value (center of the radar plot). I would like the plot to convey this arbitrary value somehow and a color gradient would be a reasonable way to do it (almost like a heatmap). This would help compare two radar plots to one another when the arbitrary value is different.

MY radar plots currently do not provide information on what this arbitrary value might be but they show the mean differences in grades of subjects V1-V9 compared to the center of the radar plot. If I have one radar plot with this center value being 50 and another being 30, but the mean differences in grade V1-V9 is the same in both plots, I'd like to have a color gradient that corresponds to the magnitude of such values. I am not sure how to include that or if there is such a function with the fmsb package

```
library(fmsb)   
df = as.data.frame(rbind(rep(50,9), rep(0,9), c(-34, -14, 12, -3, 11, 23, 10, 1.4, -43)))   
radarchart(df, maxmin =F, axistype = 1, 
           pfcol=c(NA, rgb(1,0,0,0.6), rgb(0,0,1,0.6)),
           caxislabels = c("10%", "20%", "30%", "40%", "50%"),
           pcol= c("black", "red", "blue"))
```

Now assume we reproduce the chart but in one situation the arbitary grade in the center is 50 and in another it is 20. I would like them to have color gradients (rather than plain red and blue) to reflect a higher grade in the center (for the 50) with a relatively lower variation towards V1-V9 and in the other chart reflect a lower center (20) with a relatively higher variation towards V1-V9 (since a 10 grade higher compared to 20 is more meaningful than a 10 grade higher than a 50)